# is it okay to delete ntuser.dat from C:\programdata?

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus

I ran the Combofix program to check for malware and it deleted ntuser.dat from C:\programdata. Is the file necessary in that folder?

Comment: no, don't delete.

Comment: Combofix saved a backup of ntuser.dat. If I copy that back to C:\programdata, will that solve the problem?

Comment: @Sathya: Sounds like it's too late...

Comment: Ntuser.dat in c:\programdata ? That's not a standard location of this type of file. Ntuser.dat contains user registry. So it should be fine withou it. I would try to use antivirus check before delete, but...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ntuser.dat is the HKEY_CURRENT_USER hive for the registry.

It should be under your user folder like C:\Users\Your User Name. I thought the file deleted from C:\programdata\ is a malware or at least not for user registry.

Keep the backup and reboot. if everything works fine, don't recover the backup file.